# How to replace the subscribed topic for a Device/User in FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently I've a requirement in which what I have to do is to subscribe different topic for different type of users.
The use case is if multiple users logs in from single device what is the method to subscribe and unsubscribe the topic according to the Logged In User's Role.
A quick solution comes up is to unsubscribe all topics and then subscribe the appropriate one.

Suppose user3 logged-in into the application. Unsubscribe all topics.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Topic1");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Topic2");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Topic3");
```

Then subscribe the appropriate one.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Topic3");
```

I am not sure this is the best solution for this problem. Anybody has a better approach? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have the list of topics the corresponding user is subscribed to. Every time they sign in/out, you subscribe/unsubscribe the topics based on the list accordingly.

Comment: Actually I want to check what are the topics that are subscribed so I would need to unsubscribe only a few topics but not all including the ones which were never subscribed. Is there a way to find all the topics that are currently subscribed

Comment: There isn't. You have to maintain that list on your own. Probably saving the topic name under the device's list.

Comment: yeah, it make sense

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, unsubscribe when user logs out and subscribe again when new user logs in.

Comment: No I want to keep receiving notification for old user even if he logged out and until a new user gets logged in the app.